# React when a pod is created (hook)

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to know if it's possible to get information from a pod when it's just created.

I'm spending time in developing a kubernetes controller process that reacts itself when a pod is created in cluster.

When a pod is just created, the service has to be able to get some basic information from pod. For example, ip, annotations...

I'd like to use a java service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use kubernetes

> api-server

to get information regarding

> endpoints (service)

. Kubernetes expose its API via REST so, you can use anything to communicate. Also, verify the results using '`kubectl`' tool while development. For example, if you want to monitor pods related to service say, myservice.

```
kubectl get endpoints <myservice_pod> --watch
```

This will notify you with any activity with pods related to myservice. IMO, in java you have to use polling mechanism to mimic `--watch` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you use kubernetes API client you can just watch on changes for all pods and then get their details (assuming you have granted RBAC auth)